# Как узнать в function.php на какой странице я сейчас нахожусь. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Задача след.: Если я нахожусь на странице такой-то, то сделать то-то. Это все нужно проделать в файле function.php
Пробовал так:

```
if (is_category('recepty'))
```

ничего не выходит. При отладки `var_dump(is_category('recepty'));` возвращает false.

Comment: О чем речь идет? О стандартных типах записей или кастомных?

Comment: А есть разница? Вообще о стандартных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день!

Воспользуйтесь фильтрами wordpress в файле functions.php, вам должен подойти фильтр [add_action( 'init', 'action_function_name_11' );](http://wp-kama.ru/hook/init)

По ссылке доступна документация.

Пример (файл **functions.php**):

```
function action_function_name_11() {
    // Действие...
    if(is_category())
    {
        //что-то делаем с этой загруженной страницей
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'action_function_name_11' );
```

Comment: Можно и так. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем разобрался. function.php не знает (не всегда знает) в какой категории он сейчас находится. Поэтому задачу решил сразу двумя способами:

1. ajax передавать адрес, или

2.

`if ( strpos($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER], 'recepty') !== false )
{
   // делать что-то если совпадение есть
}`

Answer (score 0):

Используя [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/):

```
if (is_page(ID/slug/массив параметров))
```

Comment: не работает возвращает false.(